# inventorylocation field in Netsuite

Tags: soap, netsuite

I am working on an integration of a bespoke application with Netsuite and there is a requirement where I have to set inventorylocation field at lineitem level while creating a sales order.

I am able to do that via soap api but when i try to fulfill the same line item via soap api, I am getting an error "valid_line_item_reqd" error in netsuite soap itemfulfillment

If I try the same line item from NetSuite UI, i can fulfill it. Also, if I remove the inventorylocation field from sale order , then i can fulfill the item using SOAP api.

Is there anything that need to be passed explicitly which I am missing.
PS, this is inventorylocation field and not the location field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got answer from Netsuite support, passing inventoryLocation field is not possible in Item fulfillment via Soap request and is not supported. Use restlet if required

Answer (score 2):

You should not be setting locations at the item fulfillment level.

You should get your item fulfillment with an `initialize` or `initializeList` operation.

Once you have that you can update the same fields that you can in the UI on the `ItemFulfillmentItemList.ItemFulfillmentItem`

generally that would be limited to setting custom fields and adjusting `itemReceive` and `quantity` and the other bin and inventory details

When initialized from a sales order or transferorder your inventory location will be filled in already.

Comment: thanks @bknights but I am getting the same error while calling initialize. we were using typescript to make the direct call but after this error I tried using the. net project provided by netsuite as a sample and it throws the same error with initialize when I use the sales order as ref in initialization

Comment: Can you include the initialized item fulfillment and the item fulfillment you are trying to save? You can get these under Setup -> Integration -> SOAP Web Service Usage Log. 
The initialized fulfillment will be in the response to the initialize operation and the other will be in the request

Comment: Request(body only) :<soap:Body>
        <initialize xmlns="urn:messages_2020_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
            <initializeRecord>
                <type xmlns="urn:core_2020_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">itemFulfillment</type>
                <reference internalId="55824" type="salesOrder" xmlns="urn:core_2020_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"/>
            </initializeRecord>
        </initialize>
    </soap:Body>

Comment: Response:  <readResponse>
                <platformCore:status isSuccess="false" xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2020_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
                    <platformCore:statusDetail type="ERROR">
                        <platformCore:code>VALID_LINE_ITEM_REQD</platformCore:code>
                        <platformCore:message>You must have at least one valid line item for this transaction.</platformCore:message>
                    </platformCore:statusDetail>
                </platformCore:status>
            </readResponse>

Comment: If you go to that sales order with internalId 55824 can you fulfill it right now? Or is there a chance you are trying to fulfill an order that has no lines pending fulfillment?

Comment: i can fulfill it through UI, when you click on UI it redirects to Item fulfillment screen. In the  querystring parameter, I can see it is passing a parameter inventoryLocation from sales order to itemfulfillment. If i try it via soap, it throws error. If i remove the inventorylocation property value from the sales order , then i can fulfill it through soap request

Answer (score 1):

If you are using multi-location inventory (which you seem to be), you need to set the inventorylocation field on each line of the Item Fulfillment record.  In the UI, the Item Fulfillment record inherits the value from the Sales Order, which is why you can fulfill there.  If creating the Item Fulfillment via SOAP, you will need to specify the value of the field in order to create the line.

Comment: Thanks Pierre, but the issue is that there is no field called inventorylocation in itemfulfillment. It is present in salesorder but not in itemfulfillment

Comment: Hi @rdhaundiyal, according to the records browser, it's called "location" for SuiteScript access (in the "item" sublist).  If you look at the Schema Browser, for SOAP, it seems a bit more complex: looking at the ItemFulfillmentItemList then ItemFulfillmentItem, there is a location field there, but there is also an InventoryDetail type field called inventoryDetail which may also apply.

Comment: yes, that field I am already providing which is called location, but the other field is explicitly called inventoryLocation which I can find in SalesOrder but not in itemfulfillment. If I don't set this inventoryLocation in salesorder, everything works fine